# SQL window function group by

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I'm fairly new to  window functions and have been learning about them recently. There is this query which returns the total sales for each month and quarter using a group by and an aggregate function. Additionally, it returns the total sales for the whole year (using a window function) and the max total sales for each quarter (using a window function). This all makes sense to me.

Query:

```
SELECT
    quarter(payment_date) quarter,
    monthname(payment_date) month_name,
    SUM(amount) monthly_sales,
    MAX(SUM(amount)) OVER() max_overall_values,
    MAX(SUM(amount)) OVER(PARTITION BY quarter(payment_date)) max_quarter_sales
FROM
    payment
WHERE
    year(payment_date) = 2005
GROUP BY
    quarter(payment_date),
    monthname(payment_date)
ORDER BY
    monthname(payment_date) DESC;
```

Results:

```
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| quarter | month_name | monthly_sales | max_overall_values | max_quarter_sales |
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|       2 | May        |       4824.43 |           28373.89 |           9631.88 |
|       2 | June       |       9631.88 |           28373.89 |           9631.88 |
|       3 | July       |      28373.89 |           28373.89 |          28373.89 |
|       3 | August     |      24072.13 |           28373.89 |          28373.89 |
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I start to loose track of what's going on if I remove "max":

```
SELECT
    quarter(payment_date) quarter,
    monthname(payment_date) month_name,
    SUM(amount) monthly_sales,
    SUM(amount) OVER() max_overall_values,
    SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY quarter(payment_date)) max_quarter_sales
FROM
    payment
WHERE
    year(payment_date) = 2005
GROUP BY
    quarter(payment_date),
    monthname(payment_date)
ORDER BY
    monthname(payment_date) DESC;
```

I get the following results:

```
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| quarter | month_name | monthly_sales | max_overall_values | max_quarter_sales |
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|       2 | May        |       4824.43 |              19.96 |              8.98 |
|       2 | June       |       9631.88 |              19.96 |              8.98 |
|       3 | July       |      28373.89 |              19.96 |             10.98 |
|       3 | August     |      24072.13 |              19.96 |             10.98 |
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

My question is what data is the "max" window function actually processing when it's used in this context, which involves a group by clause, and
how is it arriving at the calculation of 19.96 for max_overall_values, 8.98 for a quarter and 10.98 for the other when "max" is removed?

Answer (score 1):

If you leave off the sum, the amount summed by the window function will be the amount that would have been returned if it were included in the select columns (e.g. SELECT amount, quarter(payment_date) quarter...).

Because different rows being grouped will have different amounts, this amount will be the amount column from an *arbitrary* row of those being grouped.  This is almost never a useful thing, and indeed modern versions of mysql have a default ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode that returns an error if you attempt this in your query:

```
Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.payment.amount' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IP3Pc5i_)

Comment: not working in what sense?  it is just demonstrating that your query gives an error on `SUM(amount) OVER...` with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled and no error when it is disabled, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: No problem. Did you mean "If you leave off the max" vs "if you leave off the sum"?

Comment: Appreciate the answer but still at a loss of the results when ```max()``` is removed from ```max(sum())```.

Comment: ah, no, I just didn't notice that your first query was doing max over and the second doing sum over.  the principle is the same: max or sum window functions take an expression and use the value of that expression as if it were part of the result row.  and doing `select amount ... group by fields-amount-is-not-functionally-dependent-on` doesn't produce a useful result, so neither does `select sum(amount) over ...group by fields-amount-is-not-functionally-dependent-on`

Comment: Gotcha, mind elaborating a little more on this answer, please? I think I'm slightly understanding a little more. Still trying to decipher how the window function```sum() over()``` returns a much different result than ```max(sum()) over()``` with this group by.

Comment: add amount to your select list and you should see that the sum over returns the sum of those amounts in the result rows.  what it does is totally different than max(sum) over; there's no reason to think they'd be anything close to similar.

Comment: taking another tack at explaining, window functions operate only on values *after* group by grouping (though those values may be expressions that include aggregate functions).  the non-window sum() returns the sum of the pre-grouping rows; max(sum) over then returns the maximum of those sums.

Comment: Ah, I think it's coming together now. The key phrase was "the non-window sum() returns the sum of the pre-grouping rows; max(sum) over then returns the maximum of those sums.",  as well as the order of execution. ```sum``` works regularly as it does when used with groups, and ```max(sum()) over``` just pics the largest one in the group. Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing some findings.

**Experiment**

Prepare data as below. Two identical tables: `payment1` and `payment2` but rows were inserted in opposite order. (`create table payment2 as select * from payment1 order by payment_date desc`)

```
payment_date|amount|
------------+------+
  2020-05-01|     1|
  2020-05-02|     2|
  2020-05-03|     3|
  2020-06-01|     4|
  2020-06-02|     5|
  2020-06-03|     6|
  2020-07-01|     7|
  2020-07-02|     8|
  2020-07-03|     9|
  2020-08-01|    10|
  2020-08-02|    11|
  2020-08-03|    12|
```

Calculating monthly_sales for reference:

```
quarter|month_name|amount|monthly_sales|
-------+----------+------+-------------+
      2|May       |     1|            6|
      2|May       |     2|            6|
      2|May       |     3|            6|
      2|June      |     4|           15|
      2|June      |     5|           15|
      2|June      |     6|           15|
      3|July      |     7|           24|
      3|July      |     8|           24|
      3|July      |     9|           24|
      3|August    |    10|           33|
      3|August    |    11|           33|
      3|August    |    12|           33|
```

1. apply `max(sum())` and everything looks good.

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|max_overall_amount|max_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                33|               15|
      2|June      |           15|                33|               15|
      3|July      |           24|                33|               33|
      3|August    |           33|                33|               33|
```

2. apply `sum()` only. It seems that only first row of each month is picked (I tried use CTE to order by `payment_date` `ASC` or `DESC` but no difference)

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|sum_overall_amount|sum_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                22|                5|
      2|June      |           15|                22|                5|
      3|July      |           24|                22|               17|
      3|August    |           33|                22|               17|

-- 22 = 1 + 4 + 7 + 10 --> first row of each month
--  5 = 1 + 4          --> first row of May, June
-- 17 = 7 + 10         --> first row of July, August
```

query against `payment2`:

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|sum_overall_amount|sum_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                30|                9|
      2|June      |           15|                30|                9|
      3|July      |           24|                30|               21|
      3|August    |           33|                30|               21|

-- 30 = 3 + 6 + 9 + 12  --> first row of each month  in `payment2`
```

3. apply max().

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|max_overall_amount|max_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                10|                4|
      2|June      |           15|                10|                4|
      3|July      |           24|                10|               10|
      3|August    |           33|                10|               10|

--  4 = max(1,  4) --> first row of May , June
-- 10 = max(7, 10) --> first row of July, August
```

query against `payment2`:

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|max_overall_amount|max_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                12|                6|
      2|June      |           15|                12|                6|
      3|July      |           24|                12|               12|
      3|August    |           33|                12|               12|

--  6 = max(3,  6) --> first row of May, Jun in `payment2`
-- 12 = max(9, 12) --> first row of July, August in `payment2`
```

4. apply min():

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|min_overall_amount|min_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                 1|                1|
      2|June      |           15|                 1|                1|
      3|July      |           24|                 1|                7|
      3|August    |           33|                 1|                7|

-- 1 = min(1,  4) --> first row of May, June
-- 7 = min(7, 10) --> first row of July, August
```

query against `payment2`:

```
quarter|month_name|monthly_sales|min_overall_amount|min_quarter_sales|
-------+----------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
      2|May       |            6|                 3|                3|
      2|June      |           15|                 3|                3|
      3|July      |           24|                 3|                9|
      3|August    |           33|                 3|                9|

-- 3  = min(3,  6) --> first row of May, June in `payment2`
-- 9  = min(9, 12) --> first row of July, August in `payment2`
```

**Environment**:

- MySQL 8.0.26 on Centos Stream 8
- Disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in session.

**Observations**:

- `GROUP BY` quarter & month seems to make MySQL to pick the first row in physical location of each group (May, June, July, August) and then apply aggregate functions (sum(), max(), min())
- data in `payment1` and `payment1` are identical but stored in opposite order and the same queries ran against the two tables returned different results.
- data stored order in a table may change over time. Therefore, the outcome could be also changed.
- If the above are true, disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` `sql_mode` may be harmful due to inconsistent results.

**A Question for @Robert**:
Could you please run similar experiments on your end to see what the outcome looks like? My environment is very limited. Thanks